# Negate part of regex

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm looking for a way to match (pseudo code)

```
grep -E '^[aoueiy]*(!sch|s|z)+.*$'
```

where `!` is no match

It should match `sabc`, `zabc` and `as`, but not `usch`.

How can I write this in a proper way with grep?

Comment: Could you just use the `-v` option of grep to invert the search: `grep -v 'sch'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps with `grep -E`:

```
grep -E '^[aeiouy]*(s|z)+' infile | grep -vE '^[aeiouy]*(sch)+'
```

The first pass gets all the desired matches plus the undesired, `usch` style matches; the second pass removes the undesired ones.

For an input file containing

```
sabc
zabc
as
usch
```

the output is

```
$ grep -E '^[aeiouy]*(s|z)+' infile | grep -vE '^[aeiouy]*(sch)+'
sabc
zabc
as
```

Or, building on [redneb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39681664/3266847), using `grep -P`<sup>1</sup> and a negative look-ahead:

```
$ grep -P '^[aeiouy]*(?!sch)[sz]+' infile
sabc
zabc
as
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Notice that the `-P` option requires GNU grep.

Comment: The last `grep` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @EdMorton Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

```
grep -E '^[aoueiy]*(!sch|s|z)+.*$'
```

but whatever it is, just use awk. For example this is one interpretation of what you might mean by the above command:

```
awk '/^[aoueiy]*[sz]/ && !/^[aoueiy]*sch/'
```

or with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() to remove the redundant specification of `^[aoueiy]*`:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[aoueiy]*([sz].*)/,a) && (a[1] !~ /^sch/)'
```

Comment: It works as I wanted except I want it as one expression. If I further expand it and want to have `'^[aoueiy]*(!sch|s|z)+[aoueiy]*(!sch|s|z)+.*$'`, it might be too complicated.

Comment: wrt `I want it as one expression` I assume you mean one regexp and if so - why? Not everything can/should be expressed as one regexp. That regexp you wrote is NOT the equivalent of the compound condition in the awk statement in my answer. Yes what you want as a single regexp WILL be too complicated and/or only work in some `grep`s (e.g. GNU grep for `-P`).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-P` mode in `grep`, then you could use a negative lookahead like so:

```
grep -P '^[aoueiy]*(?!sch|s|z).*$'
```

This matches `[aoueiy]*` at the beginning of a line provided that it is not followed by one of `sch`, `s`, `z`.

Also note that the `.*$` at the end of the regex is redundant, so you can just do:

```
grep -P '^[aoueiy]*(?!sch|s|z)'
```

Comment: You need the extra parenthesis `(?!sch)` to work as expected.